# How to NOT use the built-in login form from Azure AD B2C

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly, msal.js, microsoft-identity-platform

I followed [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/blob/main/WebApp-OIDC/B2C/README.md) and a lot of other tutorials and documentation and ALL of them describes the login flow where, when the user wants to log in in the app, an popup from Azure AD appears or a redirect to Azure AD occurs.

I understand this is the most secure way to integrating my App with Azure AD B2C but my requirements are to use my local hosted and custom developed login page (not the one I can customize in the Azure B2C Portal).
Is there a way to implement the flow I describing here? I mean:

- Show a login form to the user and ask for a username and password
- Call some Azure AD B2C endpoint passing the username and password
- Receive back and token/claim that tells me if the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: I think the idea of the public AD/oauth redirect is that your app does  not handle the users password.  If you need to auth against your own company's AD then it's a different matter - checkout System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement nuget.

Comment: I've been wondering if it is possible to use my own login form but still using the entire Azure B2C infrastructure (not my local AD). I read something about PKCE flow that, from my understanding, can be used to achieve what I want, but I am not 100% sure about it.